# Is CORS error specific to the nginx server or should I add something to my code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx, cors

I recently deployed a website for the first time ever. We have 2 servers, so to say: 'https://baseUrl.com' and 'https://api.baseUrl.com' to make requests.

When trying to submit a contact form the data uploads to mongoDB but it isn't sent to node.js or from node.js it isn't sent to our e-mail address via nodemailer (I don't know exactly) and I get this error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.baseUrl.com' from origin 'https://baseUrl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I do not have access to the nginx server but I was told that the specific CORS header/s have been set.

What should I do? Is there anything I could write in my code to fix this or it's strictly a server issue?

For example, I tried adding this code on node.js but it didn't help

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR-DOMAIN.TLD"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Example of code that is not executed because of the CORS error:

```
app.post('/api/*endpoint*',(req,res) => {
  upload(req,res,function(err){
    if(err){
        return res.end("Something went wrong!");
    }else{            
      let mailOptions = {
          from: req.body.email,
          to: '*email*',
      };
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
          if (err) {
              return res(err);
          }
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use cors express middleware to avoid cors troubles. Sample usage is below. Before using, you have to install npm package by typing "npm i cors"

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
 
app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
 
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: I already have cors installed in my project. I've added an example in my initial question. Is that syntax ok or does the res.json({msg}) make a difference?